# Why doesn't motorcycle get pushed backwards by the front spring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, rigid-body-dynamics

[image: Scheme]
Standing motorcycle has its front spring compressed and thus exerting force on bike. Why doesn't that force make the motorcycle move backward?
I understand that such movement would violate the energy conservation law, but what exact physics is behind that?

Comment: Why would it cause it to move backwards?

Comment: Isn't the spring pushing equally in both directions not just one like your diagram shows?

Comment: @Lambda Yes, it does, but that's the body movement that I'm interested about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force gets opposed by metal members of the motorcycle.

The first thing I'd point out is that the wheel, by design, cannot apply any forward or backwards forces (edit: other than breaking).  Thus, if there were any forwards or backwards forces, the wheel would simply move away from the motorcycle and never come back!  So clearly there can't be too many forces.

The key is that a shock is not just a spring.  It also has a piston, which is made of metal.  When you compress the bike by pushing downward, the forward/backwards forces of the spring are opposed by the metal inside the shock.

To see how this works, consider what would happen if we slowly pushed the motorcycle into a wall with a lot of force (not a crash, but something more controlled).  You can see how, in this case, the wheel would need to transmit some of its force to the rest of the bike, causing the front fork to bend slightly.  If we did the opposite, stretching the bike, the front fork would bend the other way.  Those parts that would bend are the parts that are taking care of the horizontal forces from the springs.

Comment: Aren't the wheels designed *to* provided a forward force when accelerating or backwards force when breaking?

Comment: @M.Enns Good point edited to point out breaking.  I don't have to worry about accelerating because that's back-wheel only and the question is about the front wheel.